# Is there a way to make a Xbox one minecraft map available to someone even when im not on?

Tags: xbox-one, minecraft-legacy-console

My dad constantly keeps getting on my profile to play this one xbox one minecraft map. So when I want to use my profile I cant because he's on it. So is there a way to make that map accessible to his profile when I'm not on?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade, awesome question! Are you playing on the same console?

Comment: No different consoles and he has his own account

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily if you want to play on completely different worlds, but if you are looking to play that world with him on your profile then there should be a `split screen mode` that will allow you both to play.  Sadly it would have to be on the same world because they have not made it to work any other way.  This way if your on or not, you can turn on split screen and play with him.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused, but it sounds like Dad is jumping on OP's profile to play that world because it's only loadable by OP's profile (because OP created it). I think he is asking how Dad can play that world without using OP's account to start it up. With [split screen](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Splitscreen) it looks like OP would have to start it up using his profile to enable split screen.